# Formatting radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: html, css, forms, survey

How do I vertically align the checkboxes and horizontally align the radio buttons with the text? It won't let me post all the related code, so the full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/barbrown1996/3rwyn81v/19/).

Also, how do I move the checkboxes closer to the text? I've tried to change margin and padding of the text and the checkboxes, and it didn't work.

```
.col {
  float: left;
  display:grid;
  margin: 0 30px 0 60px;
  width: 400px;
}

.span-col, .terms-col {
  display: block
}

.col-2 {
  display:grid;
}

input, textarea {
  background-color: #2C8F57;
  border: 1px solid #2C8F57;
  color: #ffffff;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}'''
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted all of your code into the Stack Overflow code snippet editor so just hit the big ol blue **Run code snippet** button below. You'll also see on lines 89-92 that I added some CSS to also align the checkboxes vertically as well. Although, I would suggest moving the checkboxes to the left of the labels and removing those lines, but that's more a presentation thing than an issue you're having. See for example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox.

- The width of `input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]` adds all of the space on the left and right of the input itself. The checkbox and radio buttons only take up about 20-30px, so that's what I changed for the spacing.
- The vertical alignment was displaced because the input also had 10px margin from a previous CSS rule affecting: `input, textarea, select`. I removed that 10px margin and it aligns perfectly now.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #2BAB65;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588666309990-d68f08e3d4a6?q=80&w=1885&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D)
};

body::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #084A25;
}

form {
  background: rgba(6, 53, 27, .8);
  margin: -50px auto 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 800px;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

.break {
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.bg {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 840px;
  padding: 5px 0 50px;
  opacity: 80%;
  background-color: #06351B;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom:-5px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: PT Serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 600px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.general-info {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  padding-top:15px;
}

fieldset:first-of-type {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #2C8F57;
  border-style: solid;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  display:grid;
  margin: 0 30px 0 60px;
  width: 400px;
}

.span-col, .terms-col {
  display: block
}

/*.span-col label {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}*/

.col-2 {
  display:grid;
}

input, textarea {
  background-color: #2C8F57;
  border: 1px solid #2C8F57;
  color: #ffffff;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2em;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

select {
  background-color: #2C8F57;
  color: #fff;
}

select:hover {
  background-color: #6DDD9E;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #6DDD9E inset;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #C8FFE0;
}

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  /*width: 25%;*/
  width: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

legend.interest > input {
  padding-left: -20px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #2C8F57;
  width: 150px;
}

.terms-and-conditions {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #6DDD9E;
}

.bottom-break {
  padding: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Book Club Signup</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="break">
  </div>
  <div class="bg">
   <h1 id="title">Book Club Signup</h1>
 <p id="description"> Fill out the form below to join the book club.</p>
 </div>
 <form id="survey-form">
   <fieldset>
    <label for="name" id="name-label" class="general-info">Full name: <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Jane Doe" required/></label>
     <label for="email" id="email-label" class="general-info">Email: <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="janedoe@gmail.com" required/></label>
     <label for="phone-number" id="phone-number" class="general-info">Phone number (optional for text updates): 
     </label>
       <input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="678-555-5555"/>
     <label for="number" id="number-label" class="general-info">Number of books read per year: <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="1000" placeholder="50"/></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend for="interest" class="interest">What are you interested in doing in this book club?
    </legend>
      <div class="col">
        <span class="span-col">
          <label for="interest" >
            Challenges: 
          </label>
          <input class="inline"  type="checkbox" value="challenges"/>
          </span>
          <span class="span-col">
          <label for="interest" >Buddy Reads: 
          </label>
        <input class="inline"  type="checkbox" value="buddyreads"/>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <span class="span-col">
          <label for="interest" >Group Reads: 
          </label>
          <input class="inline" type="checkbox" value="groupreads"/>
        </span>
        <span class="span-col">
          <label for="interest" >Book Exchange: 
          </label>
          <input class="inline"  type="checkbox" value="bookexchange"/>
        </span>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="track">
    <legend>What do you use to track your books?</legend>
      <label for="goodreads"><input id="goodreads" type="radio" name="booktracking" class="inline" value="1" checked /> Goodreads</label>
      <label for="storygraph"><input id="storygraph" type="radio" name="booktracking" class="inline" value="2"/> Storygraph</label>
      <label for="other" id="inline"><input type="radio" name="booktracking" class="inline" value="3">Other: <input type="text" class="inline"/></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Would you like to recommend any challenges to the group?</legend>
    <span class="span-col">
      <div class="col">
      <label for="yes"><input type="radio" name="recommend" class="inline" value="1"/> Yes</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
      <label for="no"><input id="no" type="radio" name="recommend" class="inline" value="2" checked/> No</label>
      </div>
    </span>
      <br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
     <legend for="genre">Favorite book genres:
    </legend>
      <textarea id="genres" name="genres" rows="3" cols="30" placeholder="My favorite genres to read are..."></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend for="referrer">How did you hear about us?
    </legend>
     <select id="dropdown" name="referrer">
       <option value="">(select one)</option>
       <option value="1">Goodreads</option>
       <option value="2">Storygraph</option>
       <option value="3">Twitter</option>
       <option value="4">Discord</option>
     </select>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="terms-col">
   <label for="terms-and-conditions">
        <input class="inline" id="terms-and-conditions" type="checkbox" value="terms" required name="terms-and-conditions" /> I accept the <a href="google.com">terms and conditions</a>.
      </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
  </div>
 </form>
 <div class="bottom-break">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That looks great! Thank you so much. If you don't mind, can you also help me put the "other" label and text input side by side? I put a span around it and set the display to inline and it didn't work. Do I need to adjust the text input somehow? Btw, I've updated the code in the link!

Comment: No problem! I updated my code to fix what you mentioned. The issue there is that in between `Storygraph` and `Other`, you have a <br> that forces `Other` to a new line.